How to resolve "Parameter implicitly has an 'any' type" error in a mapped type with generics?
I'm trying to create a generic function in TypeScript that takes an object where each property is a tuple consisting of a string from a specific union type ('foo' | 'bar') and a callback function. The callback function's argument should be typed as the string from the tuple.
Here's my code:
type TInput = 'foo' | 'bar';

const func = <T extends object>(arg: {
    [N in keyof T]: {
        [K in TInput]: [K, (arg: K) => void]
    }[TInput]
}) => {}

func({
    flash: ['bar', (ctx) => {}], // Parameter 'ctx' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
    antman: ['foo', (ctx) => {}], // Parameter 'ctx' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
});

The func call gives me this TypeScript error:
Parameter 'ctx' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

I want ctx to automatically have the type 'foo' or 'bar' based on the first element of the tuple. However, TypeScript isn't inferring the type for ctx correctly. How can I modify my function so that TypeScript correctly infers the type of the callback argument based on the tuple?

It's a TS bug, described at ms/TS#55632. Since your function is generic already you could change it to this version and avoid the "union of tuples" issue. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

It works great! Thank you! Feel free to write up the answer:)

You've run into the TypeScript bug as reported at microsoft/TypeScript#55632. A discriminated union of tuple types doesn't seem to support contextual typing of callback parameters. This seems to be because contextual typing doesn't work the same in array literals as it does with object literals. Indeed if you changed your code to use a discriminated union of object types, the problem disappears:
const func = <T extends object>(arg: {
  [N in keyof T]: {
    [K in TInput]: { k: K, f: (arg: K) => void }
  }[TInput]
}) => { }

func({
  flash: { k: 'bar', f: (ctx) => { } }, // ctx inferred as "bar"
  antman: { k: 'foo', f: (ctx) => { } }, // ctx inferred as "foo"
});

If you want this to work with tuples, then, you'll need to work around it. One way to do it with your particular example is to abandon the union entirely. Right now your T type doesn't have any property values, it's just keys. We can change that so that the property values correspond to the type of the first tuple element. So in your example it would be {flash: "bar", antman: "foo"}. Then we can have TypeScript infer T from the argument, and then use that for contextual typing:
const func = <T extends Record<keyof T, TInput>>(arg: {
  [K in keyof T]: [T[K], (arg: T[K]) => void]
}) => { }

func({
  flash: ['bar', (ctx) => { }], // ctx inferred as "bar"
  antman: ['foo', (ctx) => { }], // ctx inferred as "foo"
});

This works because the type of the flash property is just ["foo", (arg: "foo") => void] and not the union. So we sidestep the bug at microsoft/TypeScript#55632.
Playground link to code
